# How to calculate average across multiple processes using MPI_Scatter and MPI_Gather?

Tags: arrays, c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to make a mini C program to understand `MPI`, I want to have the user inputing how many numbers the program will receive, the numbers, and then `scatter` them equally on processes. Then each process will calculate it's local average and then with the `gather` the root process will calculate the whole average. The numbers are stored in an array with fixed size. The problem I have is that the root process doesn't calculate the average and I don't know why. I scatter and gather the numbers as I saw in other examples but I can't make it to work. This is what I have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
int my_rank;
int p;
int n;
int i;
int size;
int loc_num;
int loc_sum;
int fin=0;
int avg;
int loc_avg;
int root=0;
int data[100];
int data_loc[100];
int data_aver[100];
int final_res[100];

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);

if (my_rank == 0){
    printf("Input how many numbers: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    printf("Input the elements of the array: ");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &data[i]);
    }
}
 
MPI_Bcast(&n, 1, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

loc_num = n/p;

MPI_Scatter(&data, loc_num, MPI_INT, data_loc, loc_num, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


for(i=0; i< loc_num; i++){
    loc_sum += data_loc[i];
    loc_avg = loc_sum / loc_num;
}     


if(my_rank==0){

    MPI_Gather(&loc_avg, loc_num, MPI_INT, final_res, loc_num, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        fin += final_res[i];
    }
    avg=fin/n;

    printf("Final average: %d \n", avg);
}
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some small problems with your code, namely unused variables, and variables not initialized. You should compile your code with some [warning flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html) such as `-Wall` and `-pedantic`, among others. Those, flags warning the user about the aforementioned problems.

Furthermore, you can change this:

```
for(i=0; i< loc_num; i++){
    loc_sum += data_loc[i];
    loc_avg = loc_sum / loc_num;
}
```

to

```
for(i=0; i< loc_num; i++){
    loc_sum += data_loc[i];
}   
loc_avg = loc_sum / loc_num;
```

You need to initialize the variable `loc_sum` with zero, since the first time the code interacts with that variable is to perform `loc_sum += data_loc[i];`, otherwise is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

And since the average can be a floating number, the data type of the variables `loc_avg` , `avg`, and `fin` should be a `float` as a type (or double) instead of `int`.

You are calling the `MPI_Gather` only by the master:

```
if(my_rank==0){

    MPI_Gather(&loc_avg, loc_num, MPI_INT, final_res, loc_num, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        fin += final_res[i];
    }
    avg=fin/n;

    printf("Final average: %d \n", avg);
}
```

`MPI_Gather` is a collect communication directive, it should be called by all the processes within the group. Moreover, you are calling MPI_Gather with the wrong parameters, instead of :

```
MPI_Gather(&loc_avg, loc_num, MPI_INT, final_res, loc_num, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

called with

```
MPI_Gather(&loc_avg, 1, MPI_FLOAT, final_res, 1, MPI_FLOAT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

This `loc_num = n/p;` only works fine when the input can be evenly divided among processes, but (for instance) if you have an input of `10` and `4` processes `loc_num = n/p;` would be equal to 2, so each process will compute 2 of 10. Hence, all processes will compute `8` instead of `10`. This one I will leave it you to solve. Alternatively, you can just assume that `n/p` produces always a natural number.

Lastly, instead of:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    fin += final_res[i];
}
 avg=fin/n;
```

you should have

```
for(i=0; i<p; i++){
    fin += final_res[i];
} 
 avg=fin/p;
```

You want to `sum` the local average of all processes, hence use the total of number of processes "p", and not the size of the input array "n".

Some advices:

1. if you can, declare the variable as close as possible to the code where they are being used;
2. give better name to your variables, for instance, instead of "n" and "p", called input_size and "total_processes", respectively.

IMO this improves the code readability. With all these change your code will look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int my_rank;
    int total_processes;
    int root = 0;
    int data[100];
    int data_loc[100];
    float final_res[100];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &total_processes);

    int input_size = 0;
    if (my_rank == 0){
       printf("Input how many numbers: ");
       scanf("%d", &input_size);
    
       printf("Input the elements of the array: ");
       for(int i=0; i<input_size; i++){
           scanf("%d", &data[i]);
       }
    }
 
    MPI_Bcast(&input_size, 1, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int loc_num = input_size/total_processes;

    MPI_Scatter(&data, loc_num, MPI_INT, data_loc, loc_num, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int loc_sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i< loc_num; i++)
        loc_sum += data_loc[i];     
    float loc_avg = (float) loc_sum / (float) loc_num;
    MPI_Gather(&loc_avg, 1, MPI_FLOAT, final_res, 1, MPI_FLOAT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(my_rank==0){
      float fin = 0;
      for(int i=0; i<total_processes; i++)
         fin += final_res[i];
      float avg = fin / (float) total_processes;
      printf("Final average: %f \n", avg);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

**Test input :** 10 elements, with the elements being `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`

**Result :**

```
PROCESS=0 loc_avg=1.5 {1, 2} 
PROCESS=1 loc_avg=3.5 {3, 4}
PROCESS=2 loc_avg=5.5 {5, 6}
PROCESS=3 loc_avg=7.5 {7, 8}

Final average: 4.500000
```